# Expectation of the product of two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Given x[n] is independently distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma ^2$ for all n.Show that

$$
   E\{  x[n] x[m] \} = \begin{cases}
                  \mu ^2, & \text{m $\ne$ n}.\\
                  \mu ^2 + \sigma ^2, & \text{m = n}.
                 \end{cases} 
$$

I can see that the m = n case can be solved by using the equality $E[x^2] = Var(x) + ( E[x] ) ^2$ but how do I prove the m $\ne$ n condition?

Comment: You've got it backwards. If $m\neq n$ then $= \mu^2$. and the other way for the other case.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: If X and Y are independent, E[XY] = E[X]E[Y].

Comment: I've seen that inequality but are x[n] and x[m] independent? x[m] is essentially a shifted version of x[n] so it's value strongly depends on what the value of x[n] is right?

Comment: When you said "Independently" distributed for all n, did you mean something else? To me, x(n) is an indexed collection of random variables which are independent as per your premise. And mind you, what you are talking about is a deterministic signal i.e. $x[n-m]$ is a shifted version of x[n]. This need not be true in a stochastic process.